# Passing data to .popover in swiftui

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a `String` value that changes after pressing the button, and I have a `.popover` to show it's value, but the value is not changing. I've added `print()` on each step to clearly show that the value had changed

My `ContentView.swift`

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showingPopover = false
    @State private var popoverText = "hey, I'm the initial text"

    var body: some View {
        Button("press me!") {
            print("1) \(popoverText)")
            popoverText = "hey, I'm the new text"
            print("2) \(popoverText)")
            showingPopover = true
            print("3) \(popoverText)")
                }
                .popover(isPresented: $showingPopover) {
                    Text(popoverText)
                        .onAppear(perform: {print("4) \(popoverText)")})
                }
    }
}
```

After pressing the button it prints out this:

```
1) hey, I'm the initial text
2) hey, I'm the new text
3) hey, I'm the new text
4) hey, I'm the new text
```

And shows this:
[image: text is not changed]

Though I've found a weird workaround. Everything works fine if I add `Text(popoverText)`:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showingPopover = false
    @State private var popoverText = "hey, I'm the initial text"

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text(popoverText)
            Button("press me!") {
                print("1) \(popoverText)")
                popoverText = "hey, I'm the new text"
                print("2) \(popoverText)")
                showingPopover = true
                print("3) \(popoverText)")
                    }
            }
                .popover(isPresented: $showingPopover) {
                    Text(popoverText)
                        .onAppear(perform: {print("4) \(popoverText)")})
                }
    }
}
```

It prints the same thing:

```
1) hey, I'm the initial text
2) hey, I'm the new text
3) hey, I'm the new text
4) hey, I'm the new text
```

But now it shows the new text:
[image]

I think it has something to do with view refreshing or focus but I had no success in nailing down the exact thing

EDIT: my actual application is not with the button, code below is just made as an example so keeping `.isPresented` is necessary, and it's only allowed to use either `.isPresented` or `.item`

Comment: try using the `.popover(item: ...)` version, instead of `.popover(isPresented: ...)`. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/popover(item:attachmentanchor:arrowedge:content:)

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine I've edited the post to address yours and Umairs solution

Comment: just to clarify: item: can do the same job as isPresented: – item should always be an Optional of any type. If its nil no popover is shown. If it changes to a non-nil value, the popover will be shown and the value passed in. This logic should work for any case where you used isPresented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**.popover(item: someIdentifiableObj, content: ...)** is use to pass data into popover

[image: Preview]

```
struct HomeView: View {
    @State var userObj: User?

    var body: some View {
        Button("press me!") {
            userObj = User(popoverText: "New Text")
        }
        .popover(item: $userObj) { user in
            Text(user.popoverText)
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - PREVIEW

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HomeView()
    }
}

struct User: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    let popoverText: String
}
```